# При добавлении нового элемента в массив не понимаю зачем нужен такой код

Tags: .net

это мой первый вопрос тут , поэтому заранее сорри если не правильно формулирую его.

пример кода с добавлением нового элемента в массив но я не понимаю зачем нам нужно указывать
в этой части кода, а именно * tempArray[tempArray.Length - 1] = newElement; * ( -1) !.

```
    Console.Write("\n введите значение нового элемента");
    int newElement = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] tempArray = new int [ array.Length + 1 ];

    array.CopyTo(tempArray, 0);

   * tempArray[tempArray.Length - 1] = newElement;

    array = tempArray;

    index = 0;

    while (index<array.Length)
    {
        Console.Write($"{array[index]}, ");
        index++;

    }
```

Comment: А как нумеруются элементы массива? Какой индекс последнего элемента?

Comment: там получается размер массива вводится с клавиатуры

Comment: Console.Write("Введите размер массива ");
        int lenght = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] array = new int[lenght];

        int index = 0;

        while (index<array.Length)

        {
            array[index] = index;
            Console.Write($"{array[index]}, ");
            index++;

        }

Comment: Но вообще тогда `+ 1` наоборот там лишний в выделении нового массива, если я всё правильно понимаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, не лишний - старый массив расширяется ведь.

Comment: @MBo А, точно, это же от изначального массива длина, а потом от нового уже длина берётся, когда -1, всё, сошлось.

Answer (score 1):

Охо-хо.... Указанная строчка записывает введённое число в конец массива.

При нумерации массивов с нуля первый индекс массива 0, а последний `tempArray.Length - 1`

В свежих версиях шарпа (8) можно использовать также

```
tempArray[^1]
```

Comment: Наконец понял ) Сорян если вопрос глуповатенький ) Спасибо за ответ и объяснение